# Unable to catch DmlException in unit test

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I am trying to test a DmlException in my catch block, but I'm not able to throw the DmlException error in my unit test.

The code I'm testing updates the contact owner field to the related account owner.  Here is the code:

```
global class AccountUpdateContactOwnership implements Triggers.HandlerInterface {

Account[] newCollection = trigger.new;
Map<Id, Account> oldCollection = (Map<Id, Account>)trigger.oldMap;
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();

global void handle() {
    Map<Id, List<Contact>> accountToContacts = getAllContactsByAccount(getAccountIds());
    updateContactOwnershipWhenAccountOwnershipChanges(accountToContacts);
}

private Set<Id> getAccountIds() {
    for(Account a : newCollection) {
        if(a.ownerId != oldCollection.get(a.Id).ownerId) accountIds.add(a.Id);
    }
    return accountIds;
}

private Map<Id, List<Contact>> getAllContactsByAccount(Set<Id> accountIds) {
    Map<Id, List<Contact>> accountToContacts = new Map<Id, List<Contact>>();
    if(!accountIds.isEmpty()) {
        List<Contact> listContacts = new List<Contact>();
        Map<Id, Contact> mapContact = new Map<Id, Contact>([select Id, AccountId, OwnerId From Contact Where accountId in: accountIds]);

        for(Contact c : mapContact.values()) {
            listContacts = accountToContacts.get(c.AccountId);
            if(listContacts == null) {
                listContacts = new List<Contact>();
                accountToContacts.put(c.accountId, listContacts);
            }
            listContacts.add(c);
        }
    }
    return accountToContacts;
}

private void updateContactOwnershipWhenAccountOwnershipChanges(Map<Id, List<Contact>> accountToContacts) {  
    if(!accountToContacts.isEmpty() && accountToContacts.size() > 0) {  
        List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();

        for(Account a : newCollection) {
            List<Contact> contacts = accountToContacts.get(a.Id);
            if(!contacts.isEmpty() && contacts.size() > 0) {
                for(Contact c : contacts) {
                    c.OwnerId = a.OwnerId;
                    contactsToUpdate.add(c);
                }
            }           
        }

        if(!contactsToUpdate.isEmpty() && contactsToUpdate.size() > 0) {
            try {
                update contactsToUpdate;
            }
            catch(DmlException e) {
                for(integer i=0;i<e.getNumDml();i++) {
                    System.debug(e.getDmlMessage(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }       
}

}
```

Now, in my unit test I'm trying to test the catch block and catch the exception.

Here is my method:

```
static testMethod void accountUpdateContactOwnershipNegativeTest() {
    initialize();

    System.Dmlexception ex;

    test.startTest();   
        try {
            testAccount.OwnerId = testContact1.Id;
            update testAccount;
        }
        catch(DmlException e) {
            ex = e;
        }
    test.stopTest();

}
```

The initialize() sets up the data (account and contacts).  I thought setting the account owner to a contact would throw a DmlException, but it still processes okay and doesn't enter the catch block. I also tried setting the account owner to null, but that didn't work either.  How can I force the DmlException?  Is this a situation where I don't need to try and catch a DmlException?  I've read a ton of posts on the difficulty to test exceptions in Salesforce and haven't found a solution yet.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the you haven't got exception on test because you had handled it on your trigger's code (lines 52-59). You don't need to test a negative case with dml Exception, because you handle it on the trigger's code.